# I want to get the number of days and hours and minutes from a string

Tags: javascript, discord.js

You would input like 1d5h40m and it would output 1 day, 5 hours and 40 minutes - Any ways to do that?

Comment: With all the answers given, it's obvious that it can be done. Do any of these help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input string with non digits and extract what you need from that splitted string. This will only work if input is in the exact pattern you mentioned.

```
let str = '1d5h40m';
let time = str.split(/\D/);
console.log(time[0] + 'day', time[1] + 'hour', time[2] + 'minute');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Although you would have to do more work to figure out the plurality of day(s), hour(s) and minute(s).

```js
const duration = '1d5h40m';
var formatted = duration
  .replace('d', ' day, ')
  .replace('h', ' hours and ')
  .replace('m', ' minutes ');
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its lengthy but working

```
var time="1d5h40m";
const day = time.split("d")[0];
time = time.replace(day+"d", "");
const hours = time.split("h")[0];
time = time.replace(hours+"h", "");
const minutes = time.split("m")[0];
console.log(day+" day, "+hours+" hours and,"+minutes+" minutes");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var timestamp = "1d5h40m";
    timestamp = timestamp
      .replace("d", " day, ")
      .replace("h", " hours and ")
      .replace("m", " minutes");
    console.log(timestamp);
```

You can simply replace the d h and m delimiters with your more human readable strings and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = "1d5h40m".split('d').join(',').split('h').join(',').split('m').join('').split(',')

console.log(`${date[0]} day, ${date[1]} hours and ${date[2]} minutes`)
```